# Is JSON a Regular Language?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, regular-expressions, regular-language

I was wondering if the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) spec defined a regular language.  It seems simple enough, but I'm not sure how to prove it myself.

The reason I ask, is because I was wondering if one could use regular expressions to effectively pars JSON.

*Could someone with enough rep please create the tags* [json](/questions/tagged/json) *and* [regular-language](/questions/tagged/regular-language) *for me?*

Comment: I removed the tag [json] because it does not seem to be worth a tag on TCS SE.

Comment: @Tsuy, sounds good.  Obviously I'm not an avid user of the site, so I'm sure you know better.

Comment: Remember that regex implementations frequently match more than just regular languages. E.g. you can use lookaheads in most implementations, which will accept $a^nb^n$ correctly, solving the $[^nx]^n$ problem others mentioned below.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since $a^n b^n$ is not a regular language, neither is JSON, since $[^n 5 ]^n$ is valid input for any $n$.  Likewise, your regular expression parser would have to properly reject any input $[^m 4 ]^n$ where $m \ne n$ which you cannot do with regular expressions.

Hence, JSON is not regular.

Comment: Curious, what's the superscript/bracket notation used here?

Comment: @jchook The superscript notation means 'repeated.' So $a^n$ would be $a$ repeated $n$ times. Similarly, the notation $[^n$ means $[$ repeated $n$ times.  The brackets have no special meaning. A regular language cannot 'count' how many brackets are on each side, so they cannot tell if both sides have the same number of brackets.

Answer (score 32):

No, it's not regular.  Since it allows arbitrary embedding of balanced delimiters, it must be at least context-free.

For example, consider an array of arrays of arrays:

```
[ [ [ 1, 2], [2, 3] ] , [ [ 3, 4], [ 4, 5] ] ]
```

Clearly you couldn't parse that with true regular expressions.

Comment: To obtusely split hairs, the JSON representations of all arrays of arrays of arrays of integers *is* regular.

Comment: Then keep adding "arrays of" recursively until you are happy. ;-)

Comment: Standard JSON is context-free, but most implementations only support unique keys. I moved my unanswered question from stackoverflow to: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4668/which-formal-language-class-are-xml-and-json-with-unique-keys

Comment: Note that I said "at least context-free".

Comment: Expanding on @CharlesStewart's comment, does this mean that "JSON with a strict max depth IS a regular language"? Or do other features of JSON prevent this?